# Blur part of an image only

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to blur only a part of an image. The part to blur is always rectangular, so that I can easily use the following command:

```
magick source.jpg -region 1000x1000+0+500 -blur 0x20 result.jpg
```

This works, but is pretty slow for large images. Since I have to process thousands of files again and again, this will simply take too long.

Therefore, I decided to do the blurring by downscaling and upscaling the image back to the original size. However, since this will blur the *full* image, I have tried to accomplish the task using the following steps:

1. take the original image as background
2. create a copy of the original image
3. blur the copy using down-/upscaling
4. crop the desired region from the blurred copy
5. compose the original and the blurred&cropped copy

I am already pretty close (I hope), but when composing the two images, the cropped image will always be positioned in the top-left corner of the original image - instead of the original position from the source image. This is my current command:

```
magick source.jpg ( -clone 0 -resize 5% -resize 2000% -crop 1000x1000+0+1000 ) -composite result.jpg
```

I have read [in the documentation](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) that the original canvas size will be retained when using the `-crop` operation, and that this size and position will be used when using `-composite`. However, this doesn't seem to work in my case. Does anyone have an idea why?

I have tried to use `-repage`, `-extent` and other options to define the size and position of the cropped image, but to no avail so far.

Comment: Have you tried -flatten?

Comment: @Bonzo Thanks a lot, that did the trick! Adding ```-flatten``` before ```-composite``` made the cropped part appear at the right position. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I tried running the same command as yours but on Mac OS instead of Linux. But I can't get it to work and it returns this error for me: "zsh: unknown file attribute" Is there a way to run this command without the brackets? I think that's causing my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try -flatten in your command as that is used for layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a mask image (of any shape) in ImageMagick. Though I am not sure if that will be faster than your scaling method.

Input:

[image]

Mask:

*(note: blurring occurs where mask is black)*

[image]

```
magick lena.jpg -write-mask mask.png -blur 0x3 +write-mask lena_blurred.png
```

Result:

[image]